# spring-security 6 return 403 for all request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I'm using spring-security 6 + spring boot 3.0.4 with Keycloak 20.0.2 and trying to authorized request with specific role in keycloak. here is the code and configuration :

application.properties:

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=client-id
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8081/realms/realm_id
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8081/realms/realm_id
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri = http://localhost:8081/realms/proset/protocol/openid-connect/certs

and Spring-security configuration:

```
`@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

   @Bean
   protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors().configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {
        @Override
        public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
            CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
            config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
            config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
            config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*"));
            config.setAllowCredentials(true);
            return config;
        }
    });
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/ap/v1/customer/customerinfo/**")
        .hasAnyRole("user")
        .anyRequest()
        .denyAll();
    http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
    return http.build();
}
```

}`

I expected to authorized request url "/ap/v1/customer/customerinfo" with role "user" and deny the rests. but I get 403 from server.
when I change  .anyRequest().denyAll() --> .anyRequest().authenticated() I get the data but also get response from other rests with different url.
I could not found the problem . regarding to spring documentation it should be work!
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html

I expected to authorized request url "/ap/v1/customer/customerinfo" with role "user" and deny the rests. but I get 403 from server. when I change .anyRequest().denyAll() --> .anyRequest().authenticated() I get the data but also get response from other rests with different url. I could not found the problem . regarding to spring documentation it should be work! https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html

Answer (score 0):

> regarding to spring documentation it should be work!

No. It would if the `Authentication` instance in the security context contained the `ROLE_user` authority.

In the conf you provide, there is nothing about authorities mapper: you are using the default one which maps authorities from the scope claim with `SCOPE_` prefix, when Keycloak puts users roles in `realm_access.roles` claim (or `resource_access.{client-ID}.roles` one if client roles mapper is activated). Also, you would probably need to add `ROLE_` prefix to Keycloak roles when using `hasRole(...)` (otherwise, you should probably be using `hasAuthority(...)`).

There are plenty of Spring authorities mappers samples (and of more complete resource server security configuration) on stackoverflow, [in my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) and in blog posts.